# Reading data from two Comm Ports at the same time (VB6)

Tags: timer, vb6

I am writing a program which needs to read data from two communication (comm) ports, sometimes this needs to be done simultaneously. I do so by enabling two timers which open the ports and read the data.

Problem is, when I test out the program sometimes it stops reading from one port to favor the other.

I have read that I can use an Array control of the same Comm Port, but how can that help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why you would use timers. The `MSComm` control has `OnComm` event which you should be handling. The events will be serialized for you, so even if data arrives at the same time they will be called one after another, unless you play with `DoEvents`.

Comment: In this code I am playing with DoEvents as a lot of stuff needs to be shown as the data is being read.

Comment: Then VB6 might not be your best choice. Consider VB.NET where you can move reading ports to background workers and have them report to the UI when needed.

Comment: I see, and I am reading that VB6 is single threaded. Will see what I can do, thanks my friend

Comment: VB.Net sure is easier, but if you are limited to VB6, there is a way to use a .NTE BackgroundWorker. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719109(v=vs.71).aspx